# Unused variable warning when optimization is set

Tags: c++, gcc, waf, ns-3

When I compile the following piece of code with optimizations enabled

```
double bitrate = 8 * m_totBytes / (Simulator::Now() - m_startTime).GetSeconds();
double instBitrate = 8 * message.GetSize() / (Simulator::Now() - m_lastRecv).GetSeconds();
normBitrate = 0.1 * instBitrate + 0.9 * m_resolution;

NS_LOG_INFO("------RECEIVED: " << message.GetSize()
         << " Bitrate = " << bitrate
         << " instBit = " << instBitrate
         << " normBit = " << normBitrate);
```

I get a compiler warning saying:

> ```
> error: unused variable ‘bitrate’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
> ```

because the `NS_LOG_INFO` macro gets optimized out by the compiler. In order to compile I have to add a useless and ugly bit of code like the following:

```
if (false) { // For suppressing "Unused variable" warning when compiling with "-d optimiized"
    std::cout << bitrate << instBitrate << normBitrate << std::endl;
}
```

How can I compile it without disabling the warnings, the optimization, and no junk code?

Comment: maybe add a `(void) bitrate;` statement.

Comment: How about only calculating `bitrate` if `NS3_LOG_ENABLE` is defined, or something along those lines? Then your code actually WOULD be optimized (not doing a calculation that isn't needed).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Yes that worked. Still adding some junk code but this looks much better

Comment: @TaylorBrandstetter So you suggest something along the lines of `if defined(NS_LOG_INFO) { codeblock ; }` ? Could you give an example of that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're not using that variable except for in that instance, why not just do:

```
NS_LOG_INFO("------RECEIVED: " << message.GetSize()
     << " Bitrate = " << (8 * m_totBytes / (Simulator::Now() - m_startTime).GetSeconds())
     << " instBit = " << instBitrate
     << " normBit = " << normBitrate);
```

Comment: Yes this works. Still interested in Taylor's suggestion, so that the calculations are only executed when necessary.

Comment: You stipulated no junk cod so I stuck to that brief, checking for the define of course should work too :-)

Comment: @user000001 well the calculation is in a macro which gets expanded to nothing, so this is essentially doing what I was saying, just without the extra variable declaration, which is probably cleaner. If you wanted the variable declaration for some reason, I believe you could use `#ifdef NS3_LOG_ENABLE`.